# id pointer in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I am new to Objective-C. I am coming from a Java background. I am trying to create a generic function in objective-c as follows:

```
- (id<BaseEntity>*)retreive:(NSString *)idValue unpackedWith:(id<ITransferObject>*) transferObject{
    NSString * url = [[[self baseUurl] stringByAppendingString: [self getPath]]stringByAppendingString: @"/retreive/"];
    url = [url stringByAppendingString:idValue];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [self createGET:url];
    NSString *responseString = [self processRequest:request];
    BaseEntity* responseEntity = [transferObject unpack:responseString];
    return responseEntity;
}
```

What I am trying to accomplish is create a function that can take a pointer to any object that implements the ITransferObject protocol. Use a function on this object as defined in the ITransferObject protocol. Then return a pointer to an object that implements the BaseEntity protocol. I feel like I took a Java generics approach to this and it is not working.

I get the following error:

```
Bad receiver type `__autoreleasing id<ITransferObject> *'
```

from this line:

```
BaseEntity* responseEntity = [transferObject unpack:responseString];
```

And I get the error:

```
Implicit conversion of an Objective-C pointer to `__autoreleasing id<BaseEntity> *' is disallowed with ARC
```

from this line:

```
return responseEntity;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `responseEntity` is of type `BaseEntity` and doesn't match the return type of `id<BaseEntity>`. Also, `id` is already a pointer, so `id<>*` makes it a pointer to a pointer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`id` is a pointer type in itself—you don’t need to append a * to it to represent a pointer as you do with a class.

```
- (id<BaseEntity>)retrieve:(NSString *)idValue unpackedWith:(id<ITransferObject>)transferObject
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it looks like `BaseEntity` is a class, not a protocol, so you can't use it as a protocol.

Second, the `id` type is inherently a pointer, so you normally don't want to declare a pointer-to-`id`.

Declare your method like this instead:

```
- (BaseEntity *)retreive:(NSString *)idValue unpackedWith:(id<ITransferObject>) transferObject{
```

(Note that I have changed the `transferObject` type by removing the `*`.)

Alternatively, use `NSObject` instead of `id` and leave the star, this:

```
- (BaseEntity*)retreive:(NSString *)idValue unpackedWith:(NSObject<ITransferObject>*) transferObject{
```

Also, the correct spelling is `retrieve`.

Comment: Thanks! I have made the changes. I get a warning now that states "Returning BaseEntity * __strong form a function with incompatible result type `id<BaseEntity>`. Any ideas on that one?

Answer (score 1):

`id` is a special type - it is a by-reference type that does not require an asterisk: it is already a pointer. Here is an example that illustrates this point:

```
-(void)someMethod:(id)data; // id does not need an asterisk
...
NSString *str = @"Hello";   // NSString needs an asterisk
[self someMethod:str];      // This works
```

Adding an asterisk after an `id` makes the type a pointer to an `id` - i.e. a double pointer. There are legitimate situations when you need a pointer to an `id`, but it is not what you need in your situation.

You have two ways of fixing this issue:

- You can change `id` for `NSObject` (similar to passing `Object` in Java), or
- Remove the asterisk after the `id`.

The second approach is more common:

```
- (id<BaseEntity>)retreive:(NSString *)idValue unpackedWith:(id<ITransferObject>) transferObject;
```

Comment: Great, thanks! That fixed my compilation issues. Can you take a look at my comment left on rob mayoff's comment? Theres just a warning left, not sure exactly what its stating. Might be nice to have a good understanding of that.

Comment: @user489041 Did you try changing to `id<BaseEntity> responseEntity = ...`?

Comment: Thanks, that was the issue